Access Deny on ASP.NET Core Web API using jammy-chiseled-extra images
I have created a docker image using jammy-chiseled-extra version. When I try to reach any endpoint I get HTTP 403. I tried http://localhost:5000/swagger but I get only HTTP 403. Swagger works fine if I run application in debug also all endpoints are public.

Hardware: MacBook Pro (M1)
Docker Version: Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf411d1
Container Runtime: colima version 0.7.5

Building image:
docker build --build-arg TARGETARCH=arm64 --no-cache -f Docker/  Dockerfile -t testimagecore1 .

Running container:
docker run -p 5000:5000 -d testimagecore1

# Use the chiseled container base image for .NET 8.0
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:8.0-jammy-aot AS build
ARG TARGETARCH
WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish --self-contained true -r linux-$TARGETARCH -o /app ./Demo.WebApi/Demo.WebApi.csproj

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/runtime-deps:8.0-jammy-chiseled-extra
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
USER $APP_UID
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=5000

ENTRYPOINT ["./Demo.WebApi"]


There were another MacOS service running on port 5000 that was return port 5000. After some trial and error I was getting empty responses, I was able to fix it by setting up this configuration ENV DOTNET_URLS=http://+:80 so allows dotnet core to listen do loopback ip and respond to requests from every IP.
Final version of docker file is
# Use the chiseled container base image for .NET 8.0
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:8.0-jammy-aot AS build
ARG TARGETARCH
WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish --self-contained true -r linux-$TARGETARCH -o /app ./Demo.WebApi/Demo.WebApi.csproj

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/runtime-deps:8.0-jammy-chiseled-extra

EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
ENV DOTNET_URLS=http://+:80

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
USER app

ENTRYPOINT ["./Demo.WebApi"]

